# Show/Hide HTML table column based on radio button selection

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I have a HTML table that is displaying data from database for three different MySQL conditions. I want to hide one column for one radio option. I have looked around a lot but not reaching upto the point. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

This is the HTML table that is displaying data

```
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>S.No.</th>
  <th>Email ID</th>
  <th>SBI Employee ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Mobile No.</th>
  <th>Date of Birth</th>
  <th>Registration Date</th>
  <th>Check for Approval 
       <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="all_check[]" <?php echo $disabled ;?> class="checkbox" value= "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> </th></tr>
 </thead>
```

Now I have my MySQL queries as,

```
switch ($users)
        {
        case "all":
          $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3";
        break;
        case "approved":
           $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =1";
        break;
        case "unapproved":
          $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =0";
        break;
      }
```

And now the radios,

```
 <input type='radio'  name='users' value='unapproved' <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'unapproved')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> checked /> Unapproved Candidates<br> 
          <input type='radio'  name='users' value='approved' <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'approved') echo ' checked="checked"';?> / > Approved Candidates<br>
          <input type='radio' id='show' name='users' value='all'  <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'all')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> /> All Candidates<br><br> 
          <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"><br><br>
```

What I want to do is to hide the "Check for approval" column for "All Candidates" radio selection and to show the checkbox field in it as disabled for"approved user" selection. I am new to php and still wondering about this as I have known till now that it can be done only by jquery. Please pardon for the mistakes I have put in here but looking for some solution to this. Thanks

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/jquery/1122/jquery-show-hide-table-column-using-checkbox Check out this example.

Comment: @Deepa Thanks for your concern. But I have seen this and other examples but doing it with radio button + submit button, the case is different.

Comment: Please check this : having example with radio buttons. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763439/radio-buttons-to-show-hide-html-table-columns

Comment: @Deepa Yes .. Just checked it .. But what its doing is taking the radio selection. As I have mentioned in my code above, my selection goes with radio and submit button together. So this wont apply to the code. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution can be simple `JavaScript`, not necessarily `JQuery`.

**UPDATED**: [Live fiddle - updated](https://jsfiddle.net/2edn6ckk/4/) (for continuous DOM updating)

Here is a demo for a solution [Live fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2edn6ckk/4/) (change the users value to see results)

Or just check the code:

```
<!-- put this at the end, before </body> -->
<script>
// set users via PHP
var users = "<?php if (isset($_POST['users'])) echo $_POST['users']; ?>";
// update the HTML without interfering with other scripts
(function(users){
  // check if PH
  if (users.length) {
    // update the radio option...
    var inputTag = document.querySelector('input[value="'+users+'"]');
    if (inputTag)
      inputTag.checked = true;
    // if users is "all"
    // hide the last TD of every column
    if (users == "all") {
      var lastTh = document.querySelector('tr th:last-child');
      lastTh.style.display = "none";
      var allLastTds = document.querySelectorAll('td:last-child');
      for (var i = 0; i< allLastTds.length; i++) {
        allLastTds[i].style.display="none";
      }
    }
    // if users is "approved"
    // make the checkbox disabled
    if (users == "approved") {
      thInputTag = document.getElementById("select_all");
      thInputTag.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
  }
})(users);
</script>
```

Also, you can rewrite this part (no PHP needed):

```
<input type='radio'  name='users' value='unapproved' /> Unapproved Candidates<br> 
<input type='radio'  name='users' value='approved' /> Approved Candidates<br>
<input type='radio' id='show' name='users' value='all'  /> All Candidates<br><br> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"><br><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting up the code but unfortunately it does not shows any toggle in table for 'check all'. Actually it does not shows the 'check all' at all in any radio + submit button click

Comment: I changed the user value as directed but still the fiddle doesn't shows the result

Comment: Did you use the "Run" button after making changes to the code? Change users to "approved" then press the Run button in the top-left corner. See the changes.

Comment: Yes I did. But now it shows the 'check all' column and does not goes out on different user choices. Is it working fine for you??

Comment: So you want a _continuous_ update of the table, based on the radio selection. Ok, check this updated fiddle: [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2edn6ckk/6/)

Comment: Yes this works good. But again the radio buttons only change the table. I wanted it to be radio+submit. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: But, that's different. That means you redraw the table **after** submitting the form. In this case, just use the first example and attach the **submit()** event to the radio buttons. See example: [Submit on select fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ce4gwn8/2/)

Comment: This fiddle the on you just sent doesnot works. I mean it shows error msg

Comment: Because on Jsfiddle you cannot POST any data. Try the example in your own code...

Comment: Thanks a ton @verjas . Its doing the same. There is only one issue left. When 'all' selected , it hides the table heading i.e. 'Check all" but the checkboxes below it, for the records does not hides. Entire column is not hiding.

Comment: <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" <?php echo $disabled ;?> value= "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"class="checkbox" id="select_all" ></td>  This is where my rest of checkboxes are appearing. Sorry I did not posted it earlier

Answer (score 0):

I found this example which basically hides/unhide table-rows depending on the checkbox status

```css
.expandable {
    display: none;
}

#isexpanded:checked ~ * tr.expandable {
    display: table-row;
    background: #cccccc;
}

#isexpanded:checked ~ p.expandable, #isexpanded:checked ~ * p.expandable {
    display: block;
    background: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="isexpanded" />Hide/Unhide
<h1>Expandable elements</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Column #1</th><th>Column #2</th><th>Column #3</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="expandable"><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td></tr>
        <tr><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td></tr>
        <tr><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td></tr>
        <tr class="expandable"><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td></tr>
        <tr class="expandable"><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td><td>[cell text]</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort mate. Wil wait for your update .

Comment: I am looking to go with jquery because using span and css may disturb the design completely. @user3423927